# ¿Cómo modifico un valor de un "Set" en python?

Tags: python

En la universidad me dejaron el siguiente trabajo:
Crear una aplicación que permita almacenar los `N` clientes de un negocio.

*Ingresar*

La información a guardar será: *Nombre, Edad, Rut, el teléfono y el monto del crédito*.

Como regla del negocio:

- Los clientes deben tener entre 18 y 75 años de edad.
- El monto del crédito debe ser entre $1.000.000 y $10.000.000 de pesos.

La aplicación debe calcular e imprimir lo siguiente:

- `c_mayor`: Los datos de los clientes que su edad sea mayor a 65 años.
- `cred_menor`: Los datos de los clientes que su monto de crédito sea menor a $5.000.000
- `set_cred`: Que pueda permitir cambiar el monto de crédito de un cliente.
- Que pueda permitir cambiar los datos de un cliente excepto el rut.
- La aplicación debe permitir ingresar y posteriormente mostrar las opciones que pueden hacer con ella.

Mi problema vendría siento en el `set`, no entiendo como puedo hacerlo, si alguien pudiera ayudarme sería espectacular, dejare los códigos a continuación:

````
class Cliente:
    def __init__(self,nombre,edad,rut,telefono,credito):
        self.__nombre=nombre
        self.__edad=edad
        self.__rut=rut
        self.__telefono=telefono
        self.__credito=credito

    def get_nombre(self):
        return self.__nombre
    def get_edad(self):
        return self.__edad
    def get_rut(self):
        return self.__rut
    def get_telefono(self):
        return self.__telefono
    def get_credito(self):
        return self.__credito
    def set_nombre(self,nombre):
        self.__nombre=nombre
    def set_edad(self,edad):
        self.__edad=edad
    def set_rut(self,rut):
        self.__rut=rut
    def set_telefono(self,telefono):
        self.__telefono=telefono
    def set_credito(self,credito):
        self.__credito=credito

    def c_mayor(self,lst_clientes):
        print("Lista clientes con edad mayor a 65 años:")
        for i in lst_clientes:
            if i.get_edad()>65:
                print("Nombre:",i.get_nombre(),"Edad:",i.get_edad(),"Rut:",i.get_rut(),"Teléfono:",i.get_telefono(),"Crédito:",i.get_credito())

    def cred_menor(self,lst_clientes): 
        print("Lista de personas con crédito menor a $5.000.000:")
        for i in lst_clientes:
            if i.get_credito()<5000000:
                print("Nombre:",i.get_nombre(),"Edad:",i.get_edad(),"Rut:",i.get_rut(),"Teléfono:",i.get_telefono(),"Crédito:",i.get_credito())
    
    #pendiente
    def set_cred(self,lst_clientes,rut,credito):
        for i in lst_clientes:
            if rut==i.get_rut():
                print(i.get_credito())
                self.__credito=credito
                print(i.get_credito())
            

    def imprimir(self,lst_clientes):
        for i in lst_clientes:
            print("Nombre:",i.get_nombre(),"Edad:",i.get_edad(),"Rut:",i.get_rut(),"Teléfono:",i.get_telefono(),"Crédito:",i.get_credito())

def ingresar():

    nombre=input("Ingrese nombre:")
    while True:
        try:
            edad=int(input("Ingrese edad:"))
            while not(edad>=18 or edad<=75):
                print("Ingrese edad entre 18 y 75 años.")
            break
        except ValueError: 
            print("Ingrese números.")
    rut=input("Ingrese rut:")
    telefono=int(input("Ingrese teléfono:"))
    while True:
        try:
            credito=int(input("Ingrese monto del crédito:"))
            while not(credito>=1000000 or credito<=10000000):
                print("Ingrese un crédito entre $1.000.000 y $10.000.000")
                credito=int(input("Ingrese monto del crédito:"))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Ingrese un monto de crédito válido")
    return nombre,edad,rut,telefono,credito



from FuncionesCredito import *
lista_clientes=[]
respuesta="si"
while respuesta=="si":
    nombre,edad,rut,telefono,credito=ingresar()
    c=Cliente(nombre,edad,rut,telefono,credito)
    lista_clientes.append(c)
    respuesta=input("¿Desea agregar otro cliente? si/no")
    while not(respuesta=="si" or respuesta=="no"):
        print("Seleccione si o no.")
        respuesta=input("¿Desea agregar otro cliente? si/no")
c.c_mayor(lista_clientes)
c.cred_menor(lista_clientes)
r=input("¿Desea cambiar monto de crédito de un cliente?")
if r=="si":
    setrut=input("Ingrese rut de cliente a modificar:")
    mcredito=int(input("Ingrese nuevo crédito: "))
    c.set_cred(lista_clientes,setrut,mcredito)
c.imprimir(lista_clientes)    ```
````

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Cuál *set*? No entiendo.

Comment: Tu pregunta no está clara. Dices que el problema esta en el set. Pero cual set? Que es set? Cual es el problema? Te recomiendo editar tu pregunta y describir mas y mejor el error.

Comment: Te refieres a la funciones set_ que están dentro de tu clase?

Comment: Hay un error conceptual común: una sola clase para el contenido y el contenedor. Debes manejar por separado la clase Cliente y NóminaClientes (o cualquier otro contenedor de Clientes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de revisar tu código pude notar que estas teniendo problemas en la implementación de la clase `Cliente`.

La creación de cada una de las instancias (clientes) las haces de manera correcta dentro del `while`.
Pero una vez sales del while esto:

```
c.c_mayor(lista_clientes)
c.cred_menor(lista_clientes)
```

No va a ser posible que funcione ya que `c` necesita ser una instancia de la clase clientes para llamar a los métodos de dicha clase de esa manera.

Por ende la solución que me funciono a mi fue hacer esos metodos que llamas sin instanciar la clase, metodos estaticos ([staticmethods](https://ellibrodepython.com/metodos-estaticos-clase-python#m%C3%A9todos-est%C3%A1ticos-staticmethod)) que te permiten llamarlos si la necesidad de instanciar la clase y sin pasar el primer parametro requeri **self**.

```python
class Cliente:
    def __init__(self, nombre, edad, rut, telefono, credito):
        self.__nombre = nombre
        self.__edad = edad
        self.__rut = rut
        self.__telefono = telefono
        self.__credito = credito

    def get_nombre(self):
        return self.__nombre

    def get_edad(self):
        return self.__edad

    def get_rut(self):
        return self.__rut

    def get_telefono(self):
        return self.__telefono

    def get_credito(self):
        return self.__credito

    def set_nombre(self, nombre):
        self.__nombre = nombre

    def set_edad(self, edad):
        self.__edad = edad

    def set_rut(self, rut):
        self.__rut = rut

    def set_telefono(self, telefono):
        self.__telefono = telefono

    def set_credito(self, credito):
        self.__credito = credito

    @staticmethod # <--------------- ACA
    def c_mayor(lst_clientes):
        print("Lista clientes con edad mayor a 65 años:")
        for i in lst_clientes:
            if i.get_edad() > 65:
                print("Nombre:", i.get_nombre(), "Edad:", i.get_edad(), "Rut:", i.get_rut(), "Teléfono:",
                      i.get_telefono(), "Crédito:", i.get_credito())

    @staticmethod # <--------------- ACA
    def cred_menor(lst_clientes):
        print("Lista de personas con crédito menor a $5.000.000:")
        for i in lst_clientes:
            if i.get_credito() < 5000000:
                print("Nombre:", i.get_nombre(), "Edad:", i.get_edad(), "Rut:", i.get_rut(), "Teléfono:",
                      i.get_telefono(), "Crédito:", i.get_credito())

    @staticmethod # <--------------- ACA
    def set_cred(lst_clientes, rut, credito):
        for i in lst_clientes:
            if rut == i.get_rut():
                print(i.get_credito())
                i.__credito = credito
                print(i.get_credito())

    @staticmethod # <--------------- ACA
    def imprimir(self, lst_clientes):
        for i in lst_clientes:
            print("Nombre:", i.get_nombre(), "Edad:", i.get_edad(), "Rut:", i.get_rut(), "Teléfono:", i.get_telefono(),
                  "Crédito:", i.get_credito())
```

Una vez hecho esto ya puedes llamar a tus funciones sin problema alguno:

```python
from FuncionesCredito import *

lista_clientes = []

respuesta = "si"

while respuesta == "si":
    nombre, edad, rut, telefono, credito = ingresar()
    c = Cliente(nombre, edad, rut, telefono, credito)
    lista_clientes.append(c)

    respuesta = input("¿Desea agregar otro cliente? si/no")
    while not (respuesta == "si" or respuesta == "no"):
        print("Seleccione si o no.")
        respuesta = input("¿Desea agregar otro cliente? si/no")

Cliente.c_mayor(lista_clientes)  # <---------- ACA
Cliente.cred_menor(lista_clientes) # <_------- ACA

r = input("¿Desea cambiar monto de crédito de un cliente?")

if r == "si":
    setrut = input("Ingrese rut de cliente a modificar:")
    mcredito = int(input("Ingrese nuevo crédito: "))
    Cliente.set_cred(lista_clientes, setrut, mcredito) # <----------- ACA

Cliente.imprimir(lista_clientes) # <------------- ACA
```

Dando como resultado:

```
Ingrese nombre: GmrYael
Ingrese edad: 78
Ingrese rut: 12345
Ingrese teléfono: 654321
Ingrese monto del crédito: 50000
¿Desea agregar otro cliente? si/nono
Lista clientes con edad mayor a 65 años:
Nombre: GmrYael Edad: 78 Rut: 12345 Teléfono: 654321 Crédito: 50000
Lista de personas con crédito menor a $5.000.000:
Nombre: GmrYael Edad: 78 Rut: 12345 Teléfono: 654321 Crédito: 50000
¿Desea cambiar monto de crédito de un cliente?si
Ingrese rut de cliente a modificar:12345
Ingrese nuevo crédito: 65000
50000
65000
Nombre: GmrYael Edad: 78 Rut: 12345 Teléfono: 654321 Crédito: 65000

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Estare al tanto si era este tu enfoque, en caso contrario me lo haces saber!